# Is it possible to remove small patches of an image using Blob analysis?

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, aforge

i am wondering about what exactly a blob is? Is it is possible to reduce background noises in the image? Or is it possible to find largest region in and image, more epecifically if an image contains hand and head segments only then is it possible to separete hand or head regions only?? **If this is possible then it is also possible to select boundary having larger contours, while eliminating small patches in the image** ??

> Suggest me, i have an image containing hand gesture only. I used skin
>   detection technique to do so. But the problem is i have small other
>   noises in the image that have same color as hand(SKIN). I want typical
>   hand gestures only, with removed noises. Help me??

[image: Here is a sample Image in which i want to remove noises behind hand contour.]

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking, do you have any example images you can provide to explain your problem. Perhaps an example input image and example output?

Comment: @Chris : I just want to remove the pixels that are detected falsely while detecting skin-colored hand gestures. Suppose that i have an image containing hand detected with noise pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [example from aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/78109d8e-4824-1c6f-4684-02e271ecb3f9.htm), any reason you can't just clear the small bits from your image?

```
// create an instance of blob counter algorithm
BlobCounterBase bc = new ...
// set filtering options
bc.FilterBlobs = true;
bc.MinWidth  = 5;
bc.MinHeight = 5;
// process binary image
bc.ProcessImage( image );
Blob[] blobs = bc.GetObjects( image, false );
// process blobs
var rectanglesToClear = from blob in blobs select blob.Rectangle;

 using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
 {
    foreach(var rect in rectanglesToClear) 
    {
        if (rect.Height < someMaxHeight && rect.Width < someMaxWidth)
            gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rect);
    }
  gfx.Flush();
 }
```

Comment: @ hometoast : Thanks, you see what i looking for, but even though, what is the reference type of the class BlobCounterBase ??

Comment: The link to the example *is* the documentation on aforge for BlobCounterBase. `Aforge.Imaging.BlobCounterBase`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at morphological opening: this performs and erosion followed by a dilation and essentially removes areas of foreground/background smaller than a "structuring element," the size (and shape) of which you can specify.

I don't know aforge, but in Matlab the reference is [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/images/ref/imopen.html) and in OpenCV see [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#morphologyex).

Comment: I have already done morphological operation as you suggested. Exactly erosion followed by dilation. The output image is as shown.